# Grails: server-to-client notification

Tags: ajax, multithreading, grails, push-notification

I'm building a Grails app which queries several API's across the Web. The problem is that this queries are very time consuming and it is really annoying for the user to click one button and wait so much time without nothing changes in the page.

The basic architecture of my app is, when the user clicks the button, the client side performs an Ajax request with Prototype library to the server side. The server side, then, connects to the Last.fm API and retrieve a list of events. When the server side is finished populating the list with events it sends a JSON response to the client side which allows the client side to create markers for each event on a Google map.

What I want to achieve is, instead of waiting for all the events being retrieved from the API to send the JSON response, the server side sends a JSON response as soon as it retrieve one event, allowing the client side to populate the map while other events are yet being retrieved.

Any ideas how can I implement this? I read about the concept of Ajax Push but I'm not sure if it is what I need. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to open a listening connection on the client that your server might connect to. Instead, what you need is a connection to the server that is kept alive and can be used to receive events. This way, you could directly return the "action" request and inform the client through your persistent event connection once the last.fm request was completed.

That said, the way I would implement is using ajax keep alive.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what you mean, but I can not find any examples on how to implement this ajax keep alive with prototype. Can you point me some examples?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of prototype, but you can simple start an "event listening" request and put the Grails thread dealing with the request to sleep using some monitor object. Now once an event is raised by some other thread, you can notify that monitor object and the "event listening" request will complete. Then you could send another listening request from the client. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. I have very little experience in multithreading, so it's kind hard for me to understand those concepts, but thanks anyway. I'm testing another approach which is based on Ajax push with the Atmosphere plug in.

Comment: @bruno did you manage the gwt atmosphere? it took us some time to get it working, but now it seems to work okay

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [cometd plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/cometd).